# Rewriting Unix Curl Commands for PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, unix, cmd, scripting

I have a unix cmd that I need to rewrite to achieve the same result in Windows PowerShell. I am specifically stuck on the login...

Original Unix Command:

```
curl -u user:xxxx -X POST -s --data '{"one" : "one/text","two" : "two/text"}', http://myurl.net/run
```

My Attempted Conversion:

```
$params = '{"one" : "one/text","two" : "two/text"}'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://myurl.net/run -Credential user:xxxx -Method POST -Body $params
```

Right now, I get the error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"mimetype":[{"stderr":"text/plain"}],"streamdata":[{"stderr":"User cannot be authenticated"}],"status":"error"}
```

Thank you for any pointers or help!!

Comment: `Body` can take a `hashtable` so manually forming your own JSON is unnecessary.  What you're getting, however, is an authentication error.  Does your endpoint expect header authentication of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks you the error is with your `-Credential` param.
This expects a credential object, not a string.

Try:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$params = '{"one" : "one/text","two" : "two/text"}'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://myurl.net/run -Credential $Credential -Method POST -Body $params
```

The `Get-Credential` command will promt you to enter Username and Password.

Also, if your endpoint is NOT https then you need to tell Powershell with the use of the following switch `-AllowUnencryptedAuthentication` paramter or it will always fail according to the documentation:

> Allows sending of credentials and secrets over unencrypted
>   connections. By default, supplying -Credential or any -Authentication
>   option with a -Uri that does not begin with https:// will result in an
>   error and the request will abort to prevent unintentionally
>   communicating secrets in plain text over unencrypted connections. To
>   override this behavior at your own risk, supply the
>   -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication parameter.
>
> Warning: Using this parameter is not secure and is not recommended. It
>   is provided only for compatibility with legacy systems that cannot
>   provide encrypted connections. Use at your own ris

[The link to the cmdlet documentation on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Good catch.  To shorten the amount of typing, you can also use `-Credential (Get-Credential -Credential user)` which will then prompt you for the password.

Comment: Thank you both Henrik & @theIncorrigible1
I am still getting the "user cannot be authenticated" error ... is this providing the credentials the same way that -u does in unix?

Comment: @EmaNekaf Depends what your endpoint expects as authentication.

Comment: just updated my answer, if your endpoint is not https you need to tell this to powershell too or it will always fail.

Comment: thank you both very much, I think it is a problem with my access rights